# Is <apex:output XSS safe any document on this?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is `<apex:output` tag is XSS free if I put sensitive data will it get executed ?
Do I i need to implement some prevention mechanism for XSS fix for `<apex:otputField`? If it is XSS free how is the implementation or how salesforce handles this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All the standard apex: tags in Visualforce have XSS protection provided although XSS vulnerable characters can have escaping turned off using the escape="false" attribute.

The security documentation found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_xss.htm) is very detailed and should give you all the information you need.

Comment: I would add that this is actually one of the primary reasons to use apex:output instead of binding {!var} directly - although I believe even the latter includes some XSS protection now.  The components, though, are a VF friendly way of letting the system off protection.